# Laravel: Send Email with Inputted Data

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to this Laravel. I'm trying to send a respond email by reading the Email Address Inputted from the create.blade.php
But it appears an error like this:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Argument 2 passed to
>   Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object
>   given, called in
>   /Users/steveruru/newsletter/newsletter/supticket/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
>   on line 221

TicketController:

```
public function index(){
        $inputs = Inputs::all();
        return view('index', [
            'inputs' => $inputs
        ]);
    }
    public function create(){
        return view('create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $inputs = new Inputs();

        $inputs->inputName = $request->inputName;
        $inputs->inputAddress = $request->inputAddress;
        $inputs->inputBDO = Carbon::parse($request->inputBDO);
        $inputs->inputEmail = $request->inputEmail;
        $inputs->inputPhone = $request->inputPhone;
        $inputs->inputJob = $request->inputJob;

        $inputs->save();
        Mail::send('mail', $inputs, function ($message) use($request) {

            $message->from($request->inputName,$request->inputAdress);

            $message->to($request->inputEmail)->subject('Alt Support');

        });
        return redirect ('home');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('/input') }}" method="POST">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        Name: <input type="text" name="inputName">
        Address: <input type="text" name="inputAddress">
        Birthday: <input type="date" name="inputBDO">
        Email: <input type="text" name="inputEmail">
        Phone: <input type="text" name="inputPhone">
        Job: <input type="text" name="inputJob">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Input">
    </form>
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'TicketController@index');
Route::get('/input/create', 'TicketController@create');
Route::post('/input', 'TicketController@store');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mail::send('mail', $inputs->inputEmail, function ($message) use($request) {

    $message->from($request->inputName,$request->inputAdress);

    $message->to($request->inputEmail)->subject('Alt Support');

});
```

Mail send second parameter needs to be either an array of emails, or a single email as a string